# Does this series stopping times marching forward?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $W_t$ is standard Brownian motion under probability measure $P$.
Consider stochastic differential equation
$$ dY_t = dt + Y_t dW_t, \ Y_0 = 0.$$
Note that, the above SDE has a strong non-negative solution.

Define stopping times
$$\tau_0 = 0; \tau_{n+1} = \inf [ t>\tau_n: Y_t = 0 ].$$

[Q] Can one show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \tau_n >1$ almost surely in $P$?

The above question is not true if the underlying SDE is 
$$ dY_t = dt + dW_t, \ Y_0 = 0,$$
since $Y_t$ is standard BM under some equivalent probability measure,
and $\tau_n = 0$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: The process will never hit zero at positive times, by comparing to geometric Brownian motion. So $\tau_n=\infty$ for all $n > 0$.

Comment: @George, oops, you are right.